# Why the disasembly of `printf("%f",6.4);` so complex?

Tags: assembly, floating-point

```
(gdb) l main
1   #include <stdio.h>
2   
3   int main(void)
4   {
5       //int i = 6;
6       printf("%f",6.4);
7       return 0;
8   }
(gdb) disas main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
0x0000000000400498 <main+0>:    push   %rbp
0x0000000000400499 <main+1>:    mov    %rsp,%rbp
0x000000000040049c <main+4>:    sub    $0x10,%rsp
0x00000000004004a0 <main+8>:    mov    $0x401999999999999a,%rax
0x00000000004004aa <main+18>:   mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)
0x00000000004004ae <main+22>:   movsd  -0x8(%rbp),%xmm0
0x00000000004004b3 <main+27>:   mov    $0x4005c8,%edi
0x00000000004004b8 <main+32>:   mov    $0x1,%eax
0x00000000004004bd <main+37>:   callq  0x400398 <printf@plt>
```

Why so complicated(I noticed the complexity is caused by `float`)?

BTW,what's the difference between `$0x1` and `0x1`?

```
(gdb) p 0x10
$4 = 16
(gdb) p $0x10
$5 = void
```

Comment: because if it was simple you wouldn't have asked and the question wouldn't have been closed.

Comment: Where is it "complicated" ? It's just a few instructions. BTW 0x401999999999999a is the hex value for your 6.4 literal.

Comment: @Paul R,why that float is first moved to rax,then the stack,and finally the destination xmm0?

Comment: who knows - it depends on what compiler you're using, what ABI, and the optimisation level. For me, with `gcc -O3` on Mac OS X I just get 4 instructions: `movsd LC0(%rip),%xmm0; leaq LC1(%rip),%rdi; movl $1,%eax; call _printf`

Comment: I'm using gcc and doesn't use any optimisation flag when compiling(`gcc -Wall -g` ),and have no idea which ABI it was using.

Answer (score 3):

The first float parameters are given to a subroutine in xmm0, xmm1... in the x86-64 ABI.
There is no instruction to move a immediate (the float representation of 6.4) directly to a xmm register, so it is first placed on the stack and than moved into xmm0. The other parameter is of course the address of the format string.

The difference between $1 and 1 ist the first is used as a immediate constant and the second is used as address offset or address.

Comment: Why must it be first placed on stack?Can't it be moved directly from the register `rax` to `xmm0`?

Comment: Because `printf` is takes variable number of parameters (using the `...`) syntax. By passing them on the stack, the `printf` function can retrieve them easy. There are architectures where these kind of parameters are passed in registers, but this is not the case here.

Comment: @Lindydancer,isn't `printf` eventually fetching the float parameter from `xmm0`?

Comment: It might, I'm not aware of this particular calling convention. If it is, the code sequence seems strangely long. Maybe it is conservative and store it both on the stack and in registers, so that `printf` could be implemented with or without FPU support (just a though, even if it is a bit far fetched).

Comment: Moving directly from rax to xmm0 is possible, but you need some optimization flags. It requires special SSE instructions (which may be enabled anyway, because of x86_64) and to compiler needs to know which architecture is should optimize for - for instance on a P4 a read and write to memory is faster than a move from general purpose register to sse register

Answer (score 2):

Because you compiled without any optimization.  Try `-Os`:

```
pushq   %rbp                     // save old frame pointer
movq    %rsp,  %rbp              // establish new frame pointer
leaq    0x0000004d(%rip), %rdi   // load address of format string ("%f")
movsd   0x0000003d(%rip), %xmm0  // load 6.4
movb    $0x01, %al               // load number of VA_ARGS (1)
callq   _printf                  // call printf
xorl    %eax,  %eax              // conjure return value (0)
popq    %rbp                     // restore frame pointer
ret                              // return
```

What's so complex about that?